# How to more efficiently implement these radix to string functions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, integer, radix

Currently there are these two functions for converting an integer to a string in a given character set, and back:

```
const parseInt = (value, code) => {
  return value.split('').reduce((r, a) => r * code.length + code.indexOf(a), 0)
}

const toString = (value, code) => {
  var digit,
    radix = code.length,
    result = '';

  do {
    digit = value % radix;
    result = code[digit] + result;
    value = Math.floor(value / radix);
  } while (value)

  return result;
}

toString(115, 'abcdefghijklmnop') // => 'hd'
```

However, they are inefficient from the standpoint of if this were C or things with static memory allocation. The `result = code[digit] + result` is building a string one character at a time, completely regenerating the character chain on each iteration.

How can this be streamlined so it:

1. Perhaps precomputes the size of the array in advance, and
2. Generates the character string from left to right rather than in reverse?

And how could you change the `parseInt` function to account for reversing the `toString` after `toString` is reimplemented?

Also is it possible to get rid of the `Math.floor`? If not, that is okay but would hope there is potentially a way. If there is a way to get rid of `Math.floor` if certain constraints on character-set-length or input size is adhered to, please mention in the comments and I may ask another question for that. Thank you!

Obviously you can reverse the function (somehow) and *add* a `.reverse()` on the character array, but ideally we could optimize with subtracting steps (and rearranging), rather than adding extra steps. This is to be highly optimized.

*Note*. The solution algorithm output doesn't have to be the same as the above algorithms. The output can be reversed, that is okay. Just looking for a highly optimized variant of this function that generally accomplishes the same thing: encoding an integer into a string using a character set, and reversing it to get the integer back.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you working on this?

Comment: you may replace the floor stuff with ```value = (value - digit)/radix```, not that it changes things a lot though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of digits you need for a strictly positive `value` encoded with `radix` is given by this formula, truncated to the nearest integer:

<sub>⌊</sub>1 + log<sub>radix</sub>value<sub>⌋</sub>

Reading your question, I suspect that you want to avoid floating point arithmetic, and so the above formula. So then you would need to do a "dry run" to see which size you need for storing the result, i.e. calculating the above expression through iteration and integer operations.

So here is how that could look:

```js
const parseInt = (value, code) => {
    let result = 0,
        radix = code.length;
    for (let a of value) {
        result = result * radix + code.indexOf(a);
    }
    return result;
}

const baseLog = (base, x) => Math.log2(x) / Math.log2(base);

const toString = (value, code) => {
    let digit,
        radix = code.length,
        result,
        len = 1,
        temp = value;
    
    // Calculate len = Math.max(1, 1 + Math.floor(baseLog(radix, value)))
    while (temp >= radix) {
        len++;
        temp = (temp - temp % radix) / radix;
    }
    // In another language you would allocate the memory here: 
    result = Array(len);
    do {
        digit = value % radix;
        len--;
        // Fill from back to start of array
        result[len] = code[digit];
        value = (value - digit) / radix;
    } while (len);

    return result.join(""); // Convert char-array to string
}

console.log(toString(115, 'abcdefghijklmnop')); // => 'hd'
console.log(parseInt("hd", 'abcdefghijklmnop')); // => 115
```

### Explanation of the logarithm based function

If we ask the question "what is the greatest integer that we can write in **binary** that has 8 digits?" then the answer is:

11111111

If we ask the same question, but for hexadecimal digits (still 8 digits), then it is:

FFFFFFFF

And with decimal digits it would be:

99999999

For all choices of a radix, it is radix<sup>8</sup>−1. And when the number of digits is *n*, it generalises to:

maxvalue = radix<sup>n</sup> − 1

If you move the 1 to the other side of the equation and then take the logarithm of both sides, you get:

log<sub>radix</sub>(maxvalue+1) = n

And so, if we are given the value instead of the number of digits, then we derive the number of digits (n) with:

n = <sup>⌈</sup>log<sub>radix</sub>(value+1)<sup>⌉</sup>

Which (for integer *value*) is equivalent to:

n = <sub>⌊</sub>1 + log<sub>radix</sub>value<sub>⌋</sub>

Comment: Amazing! Can you explain what `Math.max(1, 1 + Math.floor(baseLog(radix, value)))` is doing/for? Why do you need to calculate this seemingly arbitrary value? If you were to wrap it into a function, what would that function be called? Something other than `calculateLog`, which is what I would call it haha... That might help clarify it's purpose. Also, so you replaced it with a while loop, so is that while loop just simulating this?

Comment: Also, is it `temp = ((temp - temp) % radix) / radix` or `temp = (temp - (temp % radix)) / radix` (sorry, I gotta look this operator precedence stuff up I guess, but not sure.) I guess it's the latter, as `temp - temp` would become zero :p.

Comment: Yes, the remainder operator has precedence over subtraction, so it is the latter. I added an explanation of how the logarithm-based formula can be derived. And yes, the loop performs a non-float calculation to come to the same result as the logarithm formula would give.